# What's the Raku equivalent of the super keyword as used in JavaScript and Python?

Tags: javascript, python, oop, inheritance, raku

Whenever you extend a class in JavaScript or Python, the derived class must use the `super` keyword in order to set attributes and/or invoke methods and constructor in the base class. For example:

```js
class Rectangle {
    constructor(length, width) {
        this.name = "Rectangle";
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    shoutArea() {
        console.log(
            `I AM A ${this.name.toUpperCase()} AND MY AREA IS ${this.length * this.width}`
        );
    }
    
    rectHello() {
        return "Rectanglish: hello";
    }
}

class Square extends Rectangle {
    constructor(length) {
        super(length, length);
        this.name = "Square"
    }
    
    squaHello() {
        const h = super.rectHello();
        return "Squarish:" + h.split(':')[1];
    }
}

const rect = new Rectangle(6, 4);
rect.shoutArea(); //=> I AM A RECTANGLE AND MY AREA IS 24

const squa = new Square(5);
squa.shoutArea(); //=> I AM A SQUARE AND MY AREA IS 25

console.log(squa.squaHello()); //=> Squarish: hello
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What's the Raku equivalent of the `super` keyword as used in JavaScript and Python?

One of Raku's [re-dispatching functions](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Re-dispatching).¹

## Basics of redispatch

First some code that does *not* include a redispatch function:

```
class Rectangle {
  has ($.length, $.width)
}

Rectangle.new: length => 6, width => 4;
```

The `Rectangle` declaration does not even include construction code, just a declaration of two attributes and that's it.

So what is the `Rectangle.new` call doing? It's inheriting the default `new` method provided by Raku's [`Mu`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Mu) class which initializes any class attributes whose names match any named arguments.

---

If you want a custom constructor that accepts *positional* arguments, then you typically write a `new` method which lists which arguments you want in its signature, and then have that method call suitably invoke the default `new`, which requires named arguments, by calling an appropriate redispatch function with the arguments converted to named arguments:

```
class Rectangle {
  has ($.length, $.width);
  method new ($length, $width) { callwith length => $length, width => $width }
}

Rectangle.new: 6, 4;
```

[`callwith`](https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#sub_callwith) is a redispatch function which does a:

- **call** of the next matching candidate based on the original call.²
- **with** a fresh set of arguments.

In this simple case the original call was `Rectangle.new: 6, 4`, and the next candidate is the `new` method inherited from `Mu`.

## A `Rectangle` class based on yours

Rather than mimic your code I'll write an idiomatic Raku translation of it and comment on it.

```
class Rectangle {
  has ($!length, $!width) is required is built;
  method new ($length, $width) { callwith :$length, :$width }
  method shoutArea { put uc "I am a {self.^name} and my area is {$!length * $!width}" }
  method rectHello { 'Rectanglish: hello' }
}

constant rect = Rectangle.new: 6, 4;
rect.shoutArea; #=> I AM A RECTANGLE AND MY AREA IS 24
```

Commentary:

- It's a good habit to default to writing code that limits problems that can arise as code evolves. For this reason I've used `$!length` for the length attribute rather than `$.length`.³
- I've added an `is required` annotation to the attributes. This means a failure to initialize attributes by the end of an instance's construction will mean an exception gets thrown.
- I've added an `is built` annotation to the attributes. This means that even an attribute without a public accessor -- as is the case for `$!length` and `$!width` due to my use of `!` instead of `.` in the ["twigil"](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/Twigil) -- can/will still be automatically initialized if there is a matching named argument in the construction call.
- `:$length` is short for `length => $length`.
- `self.^name` avoids unnecessary overhead. It's not important and quite possibly distracting to read about so feel free to ignore my footnote explaining it.⁴

## A `Square` class based on yours

I'll make the `new` for `Square` redispatch:

```
class Square is Rectangle {
  method new ($side-length) { callwith $side-length, $side-length }
  method squaHello { "Squarish: {self.rectHello.split(':')[1].trim}" }
}

constant squa = Square.new: 5;
squa.shoutArea; #=> I AM A SQUARE AND MY AREA IS 25
put squa.squaHello; #=> Squarish: hello
```

Commentary:

- I picked the name `$side-length` for the `Square`'s `.new` parameter, but the name doesn't matter because it's a positional parameter/argument.
- The redispatch is to the next candidate, just as it was before, abstractly speaking. Concretely speaking the next candidate this time is the method I had just defined in `Rectangle` (which in turn redispatches to the `new` of `Mu`).
- `self.rectHello` suffices because the method being called has a different name than the originally called method (`squaHello`). If you renamed the two methods in `Rectangle` and `Square` to have the same name `Hello` then a redispatch would again be appropriate, though this time I'd have written just `callsame` rather than `callwith ...` because `callsame` just redispatches to the next candidate using the same arguments that were provided in the original call, which would save bothering to write out the arguments again.

## Footnotes

¹ Redispatching is a generalization of features like `super`. Redispatch functions are used for a range of purposes, including ones that have nothing to do with object orientation.

² In Raku a function or method call may result in the compiler generating a list of possibly matching candidates taking into account factors such as invocants for method calls, and multiple dispatch and function wrappers for both functions and methods. Having constructed a candidate list it then dispatches to the leading candidate (or the next one in the case of redispatch to the next candidate).

³ If you really want a getter/setter to be automatically generated for a given attribute, then declare it with a `.`, eg `$.length` instead of `$!length`, and Raku will generate both a `$!length` attribute and a `.length` getter. (And a setter too if you add an `is rw` to the `$.length` declaration.) I did this in the first code example to keep things a bit simpler.

⁴ The `^` in a method call like `foo.^bar` means a `bar` method call is redirected "upwards" (hence the `^`) to the **H**igher **O**rder **W**orkings object that knows how a `foo` functions as a particular kind of type. In this case a `Rectangle` is a *class* and the **HOW** object is an instance of `Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW`, which knows how classes work, including that each class has a distinct *name* and has a `.name` method that retrieves that name. And the name of the `Rectangle` class is of course 'Rectangle', so `self.^name` saves having to create something else with the class's name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, raiph! I really like the layered approach you take with your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my cut at your example in raku:

```
class Rectangle {
    has $.name = "Rectangle";
    has $.length;
    has $.width;

    method area { $!length * $!width }

    method shoutArea {
        say "I AM A {$.name.uc} AND MY AREA IS {$.area}";
    }   

    method hello-prefix {
        "Rectanglish:"
    }   

    method hello {
        $.hello-prefix ~ ' hello'
    }   
}

class Square is Rectangle {
    has $.name = "Square";
    has $.side;
    
    method area { $!side ** 2 }
    
    method hello-prefix {
        "Squarish:"
    }
}

my $rect = Rectangle.new(length => 6, width => 4);
$rect.shoutArea(); # => I AM A RECTANGLE AND MY AREA IS 24

my $squa = Square.new(side => 5);
$squa.shoutArea(); # => I AM A SQUARE AND MY AREA IS 25

say $squa.hello; # => Squarish: hello
```

To answer your question on 'super', as mentioned by @raiph, this is not needed in raku due to the mutli dispatch mechanism.

It seems that the 'super' keyword needs methods to "know" where they sit (in the child or the parent). In raku, this can be handled more generally with nextsame, nextwith, callsame, callwith.

But, as my rewrite shows, often you can avoid this by rephrasing the methods to maintain encapsulation.

Comment: Nice approach here too! The use of `$.hello-prefix` (instead of `self.hello-prefix`) is quite interesting as it relates to my question from a few days ago :)